# Where to Put WebRequest.RegisterPrefix()

Tags: c#, silverlight

Where does this statement go? Do I put it in my constructor or do I call it in a method each time I make an asychronous request?

Comment: Are you sure you need it? `WebRequest.RegisterPrefix` is an advanced feature that is rarely used.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm just following the MSDN docs on how to call a remote web service that returns json. MSDN says to do it but never says where.

Comment: I see.  I've never used Silverlight, so I wasn't aware of that usage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example for discussion.

```
WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("http://xamlwonderland.com", 
       WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp);
```

Now that I've called  the RegisterPrefix  method  all subsequent networking requests to that subdomain (blog.wpfwonderland.com)  will use the client networking stack and not the browser stack.

You  can call the RegisterPrefix anywhere in your code. There is no harm in calling this method more than once though according to the doc you can only do it once per domain.  In fact your Silverlight application could have some network calls using the browser stack and others using the client stack.   Let's say you want the HTTPS traffic to use browser stack and your HTTP traffic the client.

```
WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("http://":, WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp);
WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("https://", WebRequestCreator.BrowserHttp);
```

Each  networking stack  gives you different benefits.  For example calling REST services are easier with ClientHttp. Here are some details:

[How to: Specify Browser or Client HTTP Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd920295(v=VS.95).aspx)

Comment: What happens if I don't specify RegisterPrefix  then generate a https request like the following :HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp.Create(new Uri(requestUrl));

Comment: I askl being I am seeing an Arg_NullReferenceException happen in production, but I am unable to duplicate it dev.

Answer (score 2):

You should call it exactly once, perhaps in a static constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can call it in your Silverlight Applications Startup event found in App.xaml.cs as `Application_Startup( object sender, StartupEventArgs e)`.